# Binding a command from MainWindowViewModel to a Slider value change event in a UserControl

Tags: wpf

I have a command in my MainWindowViewModel that performs an action when fired. I want that command to go off when a slider in MyUserControl changes values.

What's the best way to handle this?

I'm currently binding some properties to MyUserControl's dependency properties and it's working great.

Like so...

```
<controls:MyUserControl MySliderValue="{Binding Path=TheSliderValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

When the slider within MyUserControl is moved TheSliderValue is properly updated, as expected.

However, I'm not too sure how to bind one of my commands to MyUserControl's slider so it's fired when the slider moves.

What's the best way to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Both the property and the command are in the same view model, correct? Why can't your `TheSliderValue` setter invoke the command directly?

Comment: It could. I guess this is more of a question of how to pass a command to an event fired by an element in a UserControl. Whether it's a slider change, button press, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interactivity/interaction triggers provided by System.Windows.Interactivity to bind control's events with commands:

```
    <Slider Minimum="10" Maximum="100">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="ValueChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Slider>
```

Make sure to add the System.Windows.Interactivity as a reference:

[image: WPF Add reference]

You can add multiple EventTriggers to each control. Use EventName-property to define the event on which you want your command to invoke.

More information:

[EventTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.eventtrigger?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[InvokeCommandAction](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/InvokeCommandAction)

[Complete tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125188/Using-EventTrigger-in-XAML-for-MVVM-No-Code-Behind)

Comment: I really like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you want to create custom events and then subscribe to those events in your view model. This is actually two different things.

The first bit involves creating a custom event in your control, similar to the ones you're already familiar with like `Click` and `PreviewMouseDown` etc. Lots of information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_routed_events.htm) on that. You can use the default `RoutedEventHandler` and `RoutedEventArgs` classes if you want, but chances are you'll want to pass additional parameters, so start by creating a new class for it:

```
public class CustomEventArgs : RoutedEventArgs
{
    public string Arg { get; }

    public CustomEventArgs(string arg) : base(MyUserControl.CustomEvent) => (Arg) = arg;
}
```

Then in your custom class you create a delegate for a handler to accept this, and you create the routed event itself:

```
public delegate void CustomEventHandler(object sender, CustomEventArgs args);

public static readonly RoutedEvent CustomEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
    "Custom", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(CustomEventHandler), typeof(MyUserControl));

// Provide CLR accessors for the event
public event RoutedEventHandler Custom
{
    add { AddHandler(CustomEvent, value); }
    remove { RemoveHandler(CustomEvent, value); }
}
```

So now your user control can raise this event at any time by simply doing this:

```
RaiseEvent(new CustomEventArgs("Hello World!"));
```

So now when you use your custom control you can add handlers for it just as you would for any other event:

```
<!-- XAML -->
<controls:MyUserControl Custom="OnMyUserControl">

// Parent class's code-behind
private void OnMyUserControl(object sender, CustomEventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}
```

The second part of your question is basically how you route events to command handlers in your view model. To do that you get rid of the event handler and user an interactivity event trigger instead:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"


<controls:MyUserControl>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Custom">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CustomCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

</controls:MyUserControl>
```

Then back in your view model you create a handler for it:

```
private ICommand _CustomCommand;
public ICommand CustomCommand => this._CustomCommand ?? (this._CustomCommand = new RelayCommand<CustomEventArgs>(OnCustom));

private void OnCustom(CustomEventArgs args)
{
    // do something here
}
```

Make sense?